# JSP pages not loading on loaclhost while working with Tomcat7 on Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I am working on a project for which I am using Java Servlets and JSP. Earlier the project was running fine, but now when running the project, the server is properly setup but some JSP pages are not running and others do not show any CSS applied to it.

Also console shows a warning.

```
Apr 19, 2016 8:24:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.33 using APR version 1.5.2.
Apr 19, 2016 8:24:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Apr 19, 2016 8:24:58 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TPC' did not find a matching property.
Apr 19, 2016 8:24:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014)
Apr 19, 2016 8:24:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Apr 19, 2016 8:24:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Apr 19, 2016 8:24:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2996 ms
Apr 19, 2016 8:24:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 19, 2016 8:24:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Apr 19, 2016 8:25:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Apr 19, 2016 8:25:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Apr 19, 2016 8:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3405 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you war/ear file is present in tomcat and also getting deployed. 
If not sure, just restart the server after clean up (deleting temp,work and logs directory).
Then try to access http://localhost:8080/ or http://localhost:8080/YOUR_DEPLOYABLE_FILE_NAME

If it still doesn't work then check mappings in web.xml.